# Trying to build my project in headless mode but getting WARNING: No Project matched

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, stm32cubemx

I have a project in STM32CubeIDE I run this project from the command line in headless mode with this command:

`headless-bat -project "my-project-name/Debug" -build`

and it builds successfully. But when I try to copy the same project to another directory and try to run it I am getting this error WARNING: No Project matched with my project name written with it. I copied the project to c:/myworkplace and then I run this command:

`headless-bat -project "my-project-name/Debug" -workplace "c:\myworkplace" -build`

But I got the error which I have mentioned above. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have fixed this by modifying the arguments like this:

```
stm32cubeidec.exe -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data "path to your workspace" -build your project-name
```

The project builds successfully in headless mode. If you need detailed instruction it is available here:

[Building Projects with Eclipse from the Command Line](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/09/12/building-projects-with-eclipse-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: 2022 update: works great.